# meaning of "as good as “ and ”fact“

Tags: meaning-in-context

An article I read from readtheroy.org,

> The author Thomas Pynchon is known for being a recluse. There are no published photos of him except for those taken when he was in high school and college. He has given no interviews on his work and few interviews on any other subject. The media has not seen him at all. This has made his readers obsessed with finding out any morsel of a fact about his life. But a certain type of reader has also railed against his work because of his lack of biography, arguing indirectly that a writer can only be considered great if we can be sure of what his world actually is, **as if to suggest that a fiction is only as good as the fact that produced it**. These readers miss the point entirely. Privacy is paramount, and fiction should only be read as fiction. The fact that an author is known for being unknown should make no difference, as it does to the public. Think of the obsession with finding anything out about J.D. Salinger, a man who didn’t even publish books after locking himself away from the world. This, interestingly, raised the cultural cache of his earlier works, as Salinger, unlike other authors, did not have to face the realities of declining talent or inconsistent output, making him, like Mozart, an artist that seemingly died at the heights of his talent. And it’s worse for Pynchon, who has continued to produce inconsistently staggering works even from his supposed hermitage.

> Interestingly, Thomas Pynchon has apparently not lived the life of a hermit at all. Rather, he’s just chosen to remain very private since even before he published his debut novel, V, in 1963. A reviewer of that book labeled Pynchon a “recluse” because he lived in Mexico and refused to do publicity tours for the book. Since then, that label stuck, even though Pynchon hasn’t technically sealed himself off. He still goes out and sees friends, the way any normal non-famous person would. Pynchon just eschews being photographed and giving interviews in order to keep the anonymity in the real world that all of us take for granted. In his own words, “’recluse’ is a code-word generated by journalists” that means “doesn’t like to talk to reporters.” Pynchon has had some fun with his “recluse” status though. He sent a comedian to collect his National Book Award for Gravity’s Rainbow, and since no one knew what Pynchon looked like, the audience assumed it was Pynchon himself and let the comedian ramble on end for an entire speech. Pynchon also did a guest voice on The Simpsons twice, once with himself drawn on the screen, only with himself covered by a paper bag.

> **Still, Pynchon readers have attempted to connect his fiction to his fact**. Reviews of 2009’s Inherent Vice, set in Southern California in 1970, often mentioned that Pynchon was rumored to live in Manhattan Beach in the late 1960s and early 1970s, as if the author could not have known the experience without living it (this is an especially absurd proclamation to make about Pynchon, whose most popular work, Gravity’s Rainbow, is set in World War II, when Pynchon was still a child, but which is painstakingly detailed to the point of demonstrating the most arcane and obscure pop culture minutiae and fads of the war years). Why can’t the public just let a work speak for itself?

I wonder what does these 2 sentences mean?

- "as good as" : equal?
- "his fact" ： his life?

---

https://www.newyorker.com/culture/persons-of-interest/the-jujitsu-master-turning-an-ancient-art-into-a-modern-science

I found another example of "only as good as", which seems to have the meaning of "dpend on"?

> Danaher collects knives, which he considers a complex metaphor for his sport, one that he elaborated on for five minutes: “A knife can be used to make a sandwich; a knife can be used to save somebody’s life—as you’re struggling to get out of a car, you can cut the seatbelt and escape—a knife can be used to serve justice, it can be used for murder. It can be used for the greatest things, the most mundane things, and the most terrible things. It’s morally neutral. **It’s only as good as its owner.** Jujitsu is exactly the same. Jujitsu doesn’t make you good, it doesn’t make you bad. It will just reinforce what you already are. If you’re an asshole, it will make you a worse asshole. If you’re a good person, it will make you a better person.” He added, “I like to have my room arranged in such a way that the first and last thing I see every day—when I wake in the morning, when I go to sleep at night—are my blades next to me. They’re a daily reminder of what we do.” Finally, I dared to ask about his personal life, and he didn’t hesitate to answer: “When I try to get outside of jujitsu, it’s almost always done through sex, but I can’t really talk about that.”

Comment: The critics are trying to say that fiction can be no better than the (experience of the) author who created it, and if nothing is known of the author, their work can't be any good.

Comment: Thank you. I found another sentence, and updated my post. Could you tell me whether these 2 examples have the same usage/meaning of "only as good as".

Comment: It is similar to saying "A workman is only as good as their tools." The comparison "as [adjective] as [noun]" is in common use.

Comment: yes, I know the as ... as structure (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-as).  The problem to me is what is being compared in my examples also yours, does it mean they are the same good?

Comment: and Dicts say "as good as" is "almost".(https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+good+as)  Somehow I don't think it fits there in the article. That's why I ask for help.

Comment: In your Farlex link, the first meaning given is "The same quality as; comparable to." The *second* meaning says "almost".

Comment: I meant to say both the meanings in dictionary didn't help me in understanding the article.  Anyway, thank you for your help.